# How to rewrite an URL to include an additional path?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rule in my file .htaccess so that an additional path is included in the URL.
For example, the following request:

```
http://hostname/category/article.html
```

should be translated into:

```
http://hostname/main-category/category/article.html
```

I've tried adding this expression:

```
RewriteRule ^/category/(.+)$ /main-category/category/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteBase /
```

However the pages of that category are not reachable any more. Obviously the rewrite expression is uncorrect. 
Here is the .htaccess file I have in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.


## I HAVE TRIED ADDING CUSTOM RULES HERE


## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: I've installed a Joomla extension for activating rewriting. As the request is slightly different I'll start a new thread for it.

Comment: Can I ask what's motivating this?   Reason being is that the URL structure is used by joomla to route incoming requests,  so altering this at the server level leaves Joomla unaware of the change. This is probably why the page isn't loading.   Depending on why, there could be an easier way to do this using hidden menus via the back end interface?